LaTex output files go to wrong directory
I reinstalled my Devuan operating system. My practice had been to issue the lualatex command in emacs that is provided bv AUCTeX to process tex files. Normally the output files such as .aux and .pdf ended up in same directory as the .tex source file.
However, now The output files instead end up a "build" directory. If I comment that directory a new one is automatically created. I want to recover the original destination for LaTeX output files---the same directory as the .tex source file.
If I run lualatex on the .tex file from from a terminal, the output files end up where I want them. So I  suspect the problem may be with AUCTeX. However, in .emacs are these conventional options:
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'auto-fill-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)


I am not sure my AUCTeX is functional.  Now when I issue the CC command in emacs, all I get is: "Wrong type argument: stringp , t". The only way I can process the file is from issuing the lualatex command from a command prompt.

I'm not sure AUCTeX is functional. While emcs is displaying the master file, the C-C command does not prompt for the TeX engine but instead returns the error: Wrong type of argument: striingp, t". The only way I can process a tex file is the lualatex command from a shell. I tried to place %! TEX program = LuaLaTeX at the heat of the master file and define  local variables at its end:
